# Remove item column from Order PDF print

Tags: magento2, pdf, column

I'd like to completely remove the **Tax column** from items list, in order pdf.

I've managed to remove the item tax value, but I can't find how to remove the "Tax" column header.

Any ideas?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Im showing the files where it is (you can override it )

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/DefaultInvoice.php

Remove this on draw() function:

```
// draw Tax
        $lines[0][] = [
            'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
            'feed' => 495,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
```

> vendor/magento/module-sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Invoice.php

Remove this on _drawHeader function:

> $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' =>
>   'right'];

Answer (score 1):

**Remove Tax from item row**

Add below code in [Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml file for ovrride file

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice" />
```

Create New file **DefaultInvoice.php** in `[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\` directory and add below code in that file

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice;

 class DefaultInvoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Items\Invoice\DefaultInvoice
{

public function draw()
{
    $order = $this->getOrder();
    $item = $this->getItem();
    $pdf = $this->getPdf();
    $page = $this->getPage();
    $lines = [];

    // draw Product name
    $lines[0] = [['text' => $this->string->split($item->getName(), 35, true, true), 'feed' => 35]];

    // draw SKU
    $lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $this->string->split($this->getSku($item), 17),
        'feed' => 290,
        'align' => 'right',
    ];

    // draw QTY
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => $item->getQty() * 1, 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    // draw item Prices
    $i = 0;
    $prices = $this->getItemPricesForDisplay();
    $feedPrice = 395;
    $feedSubtotal = $feedPrice + 170;
    foreach ($prices as $priceData) {
        if (isset($priceData['label'])) {
            // draw Price label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedPrice, 'align' => 'right'];
            // draw Subtotal label
            $lines[$i][] = ['text' => $priceData['label'], 'feed' => $feedSubtotal, 'align' => 'right'];
            $i++;
        }
        // draw Price
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['price'],
            'feed' => $feedPrice,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        // draw Subtotal
        $lines[$i][] = [
            'text' => $priceData['subtotal'],
            'feed' => $feedSubtotal,
            'font' => 'bold',
            'align' => 'right',
        ];
        $i++;
    }

    // draw Tax
    /*$lines[0][] = [
        'text' => $order->formatPriceTxt($item->getTaxAmount()),
        'feed' => 495,
        'font' => 'bold',
        'align' => 'right',
    ];*/

    // custom options
    $options = $this->getItemOptions();
    if ($options) {
        foreach ($options as $option) {
            // draw options label
            $lines[][] = [
                'text' => $this->string->split($this->filterManager->stripTags($option['label']), 40, true, true),
                'font' => 'italic',
                'feed' => 35,
            ];

            if ($option['value']) {
                if (isset($option['print_value'])) {
                    $printValue = $option['print_value'];
                } else {
                    $printValue = $this->filterManager->stripTags($option['value']);
                }
                $values = explode(', ', $printValue);
                foreach ($values as $value) {
                    $lines[][] = ['text' => $this->string->split($value, 30, true, true), 'feed' => 40];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 20];

    $page = $pdf->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $this->setPage($page);
 } 
}
```

**Remove Tax from item row header**

Add below code in [Vendor]/[Module]/etc/di.xml file for ovrride file

```
<preference for="Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" type="[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice" />
```

Create New file **Invoice.php** in `[Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf\` directory and add below code in that file

```
namespace [Vendor]\[Module]\Model\Order\Pdf;

 use Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order\Invoice\Collection;

 class Invoice extends \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice
{
protected function _drawHeader(\Zend_Pdf_Page $page)
{
    /* Add table head */
    $this->_setFontRegular($page, 10);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0.93, 0.92, 0.92));
    $page->setLineColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0.5));
    $page->setLineWidth(0.5);
    $page->drawRectangle(25, $this->y, 570, $this->y - 15);
    $this->y -= 10;
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_Rgb(0, 0, 0));

    //columns headers
    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Products'), 'feed' => 35];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('SKU'), 'feed' => 290, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Qty'), 'feed' => 435, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Price'), 'feed' => 360, 'align' => 'right'];

    /*$lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Tax'), 'feed' => 495, 'align' => 'right'];*/

    $lines[0][] = ['text' => __('Subtotal'), 'feed' => 565, 'align' => 'right'];

    $lineBlock = ['lines' => $lines, 'height' => 5];

    $this->drawLineBlocks($page, [$lineBlock], ['table_header' => true]);
    $page->setFillColor(new \Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $this->y -= 20;
  }
}
```